# Aggregate data conditional in R

Tags: r

Consider the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c("s10","s20","s30"),
                b = c("1000","200","1000"),
                c = c("3000","50","60"))
    a   b     c
1   s10 1000  3000
2   s20 200   50
3   s30 1000  60
```

I want to aggregate it based on the following data frame:

```
e <- data.frame(a = c("s10","s10","s10","s20","s30"),
                b = c("t10","t40","t30","t20","t60"),
                c = c("0.33","0.33","0.33","1","1"))

    a   b   c
1   s10 t10 0.33
2   s10 t40 0.33
3   s10 t30 0.33
4   s20 t20 1
5   s30 t60 1
```

So I get the following table:

```
    a   b       c
1   t10 333.3   1000
2   t40 333.3   1000
3   t30 333.3   1000
4   t20 200     50
5   t60 1000    60
```

That is, from the data frame "e" the text "s10" goes into three different text ("t10", "t40" and "t30"), so the values from column "b" and "c" in data frame "d" should be multiplied by the share from column "c" in data frame e (that is, 1,000 * 0.33 and 3,000 * 0.33). And so on for the rest of the values.

Comment: Do you need to quote numeric values

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are expecting to do math operations with strings?

Comment: @Michael can you please check the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `left_join` on the 'a' column, then `transmute` by multiplying the columns

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(type.convert(e, as.is = TRUE), 
      type.convert(d, as.is = TRUE), by = 'a') %>% 
   transmute(a = b.x, b = c.x * b.y, c = c.x * c.y)
```

Comment: I have one problem if there is more than three columns in data frame 'a'. Consider: `d <- data.frame(a = c("s10","s20","s30"),
                b = c("1000","200","1000"),
                c = c("3000","50","60"),
                d = c("500","300","100"))`. Then when I use: `library(dplyr)
left_join(type.convert(e, as.is = TRUE), 
          type.convert(d, as.is = TRUE), by = 'a') %>% 
  transmute(a = b.x, b = c.x * b.y, c = c.x * c.y, d = c.x * d.y)`, I get an error. Do you know why?

Comment: @Michael there is no `d.y` column. it is just `d`